# Terminator Terminal - Able to vary the background color for each tab, similar to Xfce?

Tags: command-line, xfce, colors, terminator

One of my favorite features of the xfce terminal is that it can automatically set a different color for each terminal instance the user creates. This makes it very easy to differentiate between the different sessions.

Is there any way to achieve a similar sort of functionality in Terminator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only terminal emulators I'm aware of that conveniently support it out of the box are `xfce4-terminal` and `konsole`.

Terminator version 1.90 and above (actually its underlying VTE widget), however, understands the OSC 11 escape sequence to change the background color, e.g.:

```
echo -ne '\e]11;#abcdef\a'
```

(and similarly with `10` for foreground).

You might write a chunk of shell script that randomizes the color and emits this sequence from the shell startup script (e.g. `.bashrc`). Take care to emit it only if the shell is interactive and/or its output is connected to a terminal (see e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch)).

A quick example, I leave it up to you to improve as you wish:

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  colors=(abcdef cdefab efabcd)
  n=${#colors[@]}
  i=$((RANDOM%n))
  echo -ne "\e]11;#${colors[i]}\a"
fi
```

Instead of a random number, it might be a good idea to base the color on the tty line (the number from the output of `tty`), that way you'll have fewer conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for your help @egmont! Unfortunately my rep is not high enough on this part of Stack to upvote your answer, but I appreciate your reply!

Comment: actually all lua configurable terminal emulator should be able to do this for example wezterm, tym etc. Unfortunately they are too young to be useful.